# How to take picture automatically by programming in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I am developing in Swift with iPhone camera.

I using the following code to check the camera:

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {   
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker.allowsEditing = true  
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("can't find camera")
    }
}
```

And I use the following code to open the camera.

```
presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have reference the following [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) and call `takePicture()` , but it seems did not working.

But I always need to manually take the picture by tapping the shutter button. Is programmatically taking the picture possible in Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you use the takePicture command, add its code too

Comment: @Shubhank , Just call `takePicture()` in my custom button.

Answer (score 6):

1) Check if you have these delegates in your view controller class:

```
 UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

2) Check if your plist have the permissions with YES

```
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

If you want, I use this code (swift 3):

```
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate =  self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For camera, just change "photoLibrary"

```
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
```

3) In order to get the picture, you must implement the delegate `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
extension YourViewController: 
                             UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
                             UINavigationControllerDelegate 
{

  func imagePickerController(
              _ picker:                           UIImagePickerController,  
              didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) 
  {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    print("picture taken: \(image)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()        
    //Set delegate to imagePicker
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    //Allow user crop or not after take picture
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    //set what you need to use "camera or photo library"
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    //Switch flash camera
    imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = .off
    //Set camera Capture Mode photo or Video
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    //set camera front or rear
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
    //Present camera viewcontroller
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and don't forget implement two protocol:  **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let imagePicked                              = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagePicked, nil, nil, nil)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to take a picture without presenting the imagePicker to the user? Of course after asking for permission.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to take picture fully automatically, you don't need `UIImagePickerController` at all. Instead use AVFoundation directly.

This article will be very helpful: [Camera Capture on iOS](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/).